# What is wrong with this code, in line 20? It says nothing just syntax and I have no idea

Tags: python-3.x

So I have bumped into a syntax error and I just can't figure out the problem, beginner here. :) Thanks for your help guys.

```
import random
pcNumset =["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
pcNum = "x"
pcNum = random.choice(pcNumset)
PlayerNum = "z"
count = "1"

while loop == "y" and PlayerNum != pcNum
        PlayerNum = input("What number do i think did i think of?")
    if PlayerNum > pcNum:
        print("You have to think of something lower.")
        count = count + 1 
    elif PlayerNum < pcNum:
        print("You should think of a higher number.")
        count = count + 1

if PlayerNum == pcNum:
    print("Congrats you won!")
    print("You have guessed my number from",count,"guesses.")
    loop = "n"
    loop = input("Would you like to replay?")
```

Comment: missing a colon at the end of the while `while loop == "y" and PlayerNum != pcNum
``

Comment: The colon is just the beginning. I spot at least three other problems.

Comment: Thanks @RyanHainilem, I guess that was the problem , it still gives my syntax error for line 22 tho, idk what's with my python grammar.

Comment: @Kevin I'm a beginner so if you could let me know those I would be grateful for that

Answer (score 1):

1. Your while loop needs a colon at the end.
2. The line after that is indented four spaces too deep.
3. "loop" is never defined before the loop.
4. `count` should be an integer, not a string.
5. `pcNumset` should be a list of integers, not a list of strings.
6. You must convert `PlayerNum` to an integer before using comparison operators like `>` on it.

---

```
import random
pcNumset = range(1,21)
pcNum = "x"
pcNum = random.choice(pcNumset)
PlayerNum = "z"
count = 1
loop = "y"

while loop == "y" and PlayerNum != pcNum:
    PlayerNum = int(input("What number do i think did i think of?"))
    if PlayerNum > pcNum:
        print("You have to think of something lower.")
        count = count + 1 
    elif PlayerNum < pcNum:
        print("You should think of a higher number.")
        count = count + 1

elif PlayerNum == pcNum:
    print("Congrats you won!")
    print("You have guessed my number from",count,"guesses.")
    loop = input("Would you like to replay?")
```

7. This last one is tricky so it gets its own code block. You actually need *two* loops - one loop for a single game instance, and one loop that continues as long as the player replies "y" to "would you like to replay?"

---

```
import random

loop = "y"
while loop == "y":
    pcNumset = range(1,21)
    pcNum = random.choice(pcNumset)
    count = 1
    PlayerNum = "z"
    while PlayerNum != pcNum:
        PlayerNum = int(input("What number do i think did i think of?"))
        if PlayerNum > pcNum:
            print("You have to think of something lower.")
            count = count + 1 
        elif PlayerNum < pcNum:
            print("You should think of a higher number.")
            count = count + 1
    print("Congrats you won!")
    print("You have guessed my number from",count,"guesses.")
    loop = "n"
    loop = input("Would you like to replay?")
```

Comment: Gosh, thank you so much, very appreciated I'm getting to understand some things with Python! :) Thank you